# Latex multirow and multicolumn table

Tags: latex, multirow

I struggle with a multirow, multicolumn table in latex. So far I have this (messy) code:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {A}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {B}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {C}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf {D}} && D1 & D2 & D3 &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf {E}}   && E1 & E2 & E3 &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf {F}}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-10}
    a & b & c & d1 & d2 & d3 & e1 & e3 & e3 & f\\
    aa & bb & cc & dd1 & dd2 & dd3 & ee1 & ee3 & ee3 & ff
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Ideally the table would look like this:

[image: multicolumn, multirow table]

Subheader D1-E3 should not be bold....

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to input `D1`, .... , `E3` as a separate row:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}[-4pt]{\thead{A}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}[-4pt]{\thead{B}} &
    \multirow{2}{*}[-4pt]{\thead{C}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{D}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{E}} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}[-4pt]{\thead{F}}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
    \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
    &&& D1 & D2 & D3 & E1 & E2 & E3 &\\
    \midrule
    a & b & c & d1 & d2 & d3 & e1 & e3 & e3 & f\\
    aa & bb & cc & dd1 & dd2 & dd3 & ee1 & ee3 & ee3 & ff\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

(I would not use vertical lines together with the `booktabs` package, so I replaced it with a split horizontal line)

[image]